# Limits involving multiple forms

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

$\lim_{n\to \infty}$$\binom{n}{k}$${[f(\frac xn)-f(0)}]^k$ $=$ $[f'(0)]^\alpha$ $\frac{\times x^\beta}{\lambda!}$

$ \text {What would be the value of}$ $\frac {\alpha+\beta}{\lambda}$

I tried solving the LHS and was getting two Indeterminate forms as the outcome i.e $\frac\infty\infty$$\times$$\frac 00$ both are in multiplication and I also tried using LH rule still no outcome .What can be he approach to this question? Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried to use  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}{n\over x}[f(x/n)-f(0)]=f'(0)$$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thanks alot for the help

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Is it a formula that you have written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite the limit as the following form:
$$L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\binom{n}{k}{[f(\frac xn)-f(0)}]^k=\lim_{n\to \infty}\binom{n}{k}\Bigl(\frac{x}{n}\Bigr)^k{\Bigl[\frac{n}{x}\bigl(f\bigl(\frac xn\bigr)-f(0)\bigr)}\Bigr]^k$$
The reason for doing this seemingly useless step is to recover the form $$L_1=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n}{x}(f(\frac{x}{n})-f(0))$$
$$\text{By doing the change of variable } h=\frac{x}{n}\text{, we have:}$$
$$L_1=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=f'(0)$$
$$\text{Hence, }L=\bigl(f'(0)\bigr)^kx^k\lim_{n\to \infty}\binom{n}{k}\Bigl(\frac{1}{n}\Bigr)^k$$
$$\text{the limit on the RHS is a common limit, which we evaluate by rewriting it as follows:}$$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\binom{n}{k}\Bigl(\frac{1}{n}\Bigr)^k=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n-k+1}{n}\cdot\frac{n-k+2}{n}\ldots\frac{n-k+k}{n}=1$$
Note that the step where we pull out the $f'(0)^k$ from the limit requires the justification that the limit actually exists.
Determining $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\lambda$ should be a piece of cake now.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help , I want to ask that in 2nd step which form would be recovered L1 step